# Magento 2 Fotoroma Gallery last Image display in first position when image are greater than 7

Tags: magento2, gallery-image

I am setting product gallery image and trying to upload more than 10 image as thumbnail image but when I am uploading thumbnail images more than seven last image comes at first place.While last image should be at last place and first.

If anyone have idea how to resolve it.

Comment: which magento version you have currently used?

Comment: @BhavinPethani,magento 2.3.3

Comment: I am added 10 images for product gallary as per link:https://prnt.sc/qs8e7x in magento 2.3.3 and when i view product as website front-end then its display properly.
Can you share me screen-sort of how your product gallary images added and display in front-end.

Comment: @BhavinPethani,I am talking about frontend gallery image slider.